# Git. Can't push from windows

Tags: windows, linux, git, push

I have a server (Debian) with running `git-daemon --enable=receive-pack --verbose --reuseaddr --detach --base-path=/mnt/source` and git installed on Windows XP.

When I try to use the command `push -v origin master` on Windows it says `pushing to git://192.168.0.100/my_progject.git` and stays there. Although, cloned successfully.

In server logs I see:

```
Mar 16 10:46:36 Server-Debian git-daemon[1424]: Ready to rumble
Mar 16 10:50:50 Server-Debian git-daemon[5289]: Connection from 192.168.0.99:50278
Mar 16 10:50:50 Server-Debian git-daemon[5289]: Extended attributes (20 bytes) exist <host=192.168.0.100>
Mar 16 10:50:50 Server-Debian git-daemon[5289]: Request receive-pack for '/my_progject.git'
```

and nothing more.

On linux I don't have the same problems - clone and push are both successful.

ps. Sorry for my awful English

**upd.**

1. I run git-gui
2. Try to push from it. **Push fails**
3. Kill processe git.exe
4. Try to push again. **Push may be successful.**

What could cause this strange behavior?

Comment: just go for a refined search..the same question was answered some days back..don't remember :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bug, http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/issues/detail?id=457
We have a workaround, please see the bottom of this article:
http://pete.akeo.ie/2011/07/git-remote-repository.html

Pete said we should use ssh or Samba, I just test it with Samba, pushurl with Samba works fine for me now.

At the server, after pushed, you should use "git reset --hard" to see the new commit.

But if you just want simple pure server, you should use "git --bare init" to init the repo at the server.